# Why do I have garbage characters at the end of my character array?

Tags: c, for-loop, undefined-behavior, c-strings, function-definition

I have the following code (from K&R Exercise 2-4):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXLINE 1000    /* maximum input line size */

void squeeze(char s1[], char s2[]);

/* Exercise 2-4. Write an alternate version of squeeze(s1,s2) that deletes each
    character in s1 that matches any character in the string s2. */
main()
{
    int c, i;
    char line[MAXLINE]; /* current input line */
    int len = 0;        /* current line length */
    char s2[MAXLINE];   /* array of characters to delete */

    printf("Characters to delete: ");
    for (i = 0; (c = getchar()) != '\n'; ++i)
        s2[i] = c;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c == '\n') {
            squeeze(line, s2);
            printf("%s\n", line);
            for (i = 0; i < len; ++i)
                line[i] = 0;
            len = 0;
        } else {
            line[len] = c;
            ++len;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

/* squeeze:  delete all chars in s2 from s1 */
void squeeze(char s1[], char s2[])
{
    int i, j, k;

    for (k = 0; s2[k] != '\0'; k++) {
        for (i = j = 0; s1[i] != '\0'; i++)
            if (s1[i] != s2[k])
                s1[j++] = s1[i];
        s1[j] = '\0';
    }
}
```

But when I run it and it reads in input, I find that there are garbage characters at the end of `s2`. Adding the following code after declaring the character arrays:

```
for (i = 0; i < MAXLINE; ++i)
    line[i] = s2[i] = 0;
```

seems to fix the issue. But don't character arrays come initialized with 0 to begin with? Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Fyi, look at your code and ask yourself where you terminated `s2` after loading it with everything short of a newline right after `printf("Characters to delete: ");` .

Comment: "I find that there are garbage characters at the end of both line and s2." Why? What makes you think so? Something in output? Show the output. Also show the expected output.

Comment: "But don't character arrays come initialized with 0 to begin with?" no

Comment: @WhozCraig I've tried printing out s2 after I read it in. For example, if I input 'abc', 'abc��' gets printed out.

Comment: `main()` -> `int main(void)` It's 2022, now.

Comment: You need to null terminate the string. That's all.

Comment: @Passerby In a lot of the other code from the book, characters arrays are left uninitialized and are directly read into.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I've tried it now and you're right. But in many other instances, I didn't need to do this (as a matter of fact, this no longer seems to be an issue with ```line```). Why is this so?

Comment: @Passerby Usually just getchar() in while loops.

Comment: @avane2007 I don't know why your other program work without seeing them. Either they just _appear_ to work properly (google _c undefined behaviour_), or the code is just different. Ask another question with one of these programs.

Comment: Please don't underestimate the [risks](https://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=2010365) of unitialized variables or *not* null-terminated char arrays.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is your strings are not null terminated. Local variables (like `line` and `s2`) are not automatically initialized with 0. Their content is indeterminate.

Declare `line` and `s2` like this:

```
char line[MAXLINE] = { 0 };  // initializes all elements of line with 0
char s2[MAXLINE] = {0};      // initializes all elements of s2 with 0
```

or just null terminate `line`:

```
 ...
 if (c == '\n') {
      line[len] = 0;    // <<< add this: null termninate line
      squeeze(line, s2);
 ...
```

and null terminate `s2`:

```
  ...
  printf("Characters to delete: ");
  for (i = 0; (c = getchar()) != '\n'; ++i)
    s2[i] = c;

  s2[i] = 0;     // <<< add this: null termninate s2

  while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters according to the C Standard the function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

As the function `squeze` accepts two arrays without their length than it means that the arrays contain strings: sequences of characters terminated by zero character `'\0'`.

As the second array is not changed within the function then the second parameter should be declared with the qualifier `const`.

The function declaration will look like

```
char * squeeze( char s1[], const char s2[] );
```

Within the function you should check at first whether s1 or s2 contains an empty string.

The function definition can look for example the following way

```
char * squeeze( char s1[], const char s2[] )
{
    if ( *s1 != '\0' && *s2 != '\0' )
    {
        size_t i = 0;
        for ( size_t j = 0; s1[j] != '\0'; ++j ) 
        {
            size_t k = 0;
            while ( s2[k] != '\0' && s2[k] != s1[j] ) ++k;

            if ( s2[k] == '\0' )
            {
                if ( i != j ) s1[i] = s1[j];
                ++i;
            }
        }
        s1[i] = '\0';   
    }

    return s1;
}
```

The nested loops within the function

```
    if ( *s1 != '\0' && *s2 != '\0' )
    {
        size_t i = 0;
        for ( size_t j = 0; s1[j] != '\0'; ++j ) 
        {
            size_t k = 0;
            while ( s2[k] != '\0' && s2[k] != s1[j] ) ++k;

            if ( s2[k] == '\0' )
            {
                if ( i != j ) s1[i] = s1[j];
                ++i;
            }
        }
        s1[i] = '\0';   
    }
```

can be also rewritten the following way

```
    if ( *s1 != '\0' && *s2 != '\0' )
    {
        size_t i = 0;
        for ( size_t j = 0; s1[j] != '\0'; ++j ) 
        {
            if ( strchr( s2, s1[j] ) == NULL )
            {
                if ( i != j ) s1[i] = s1[j];
                ++i;
            }
        }
        s1[i] = '\0';   
    }
```

In main you need to append entered sequence with the terminating zero character as for example

```
i = 0;
while ( i + 1 < MAXLINE && ( c = getchar() ) != EOF && c != '\n' ) 
{
    s2[i++] = c;
}
s2[i] = '\0';
```

and

```
i = 0;
while ( ( c = getchar() ) != EOF ) 
{
    if ( i + 1 == MAXLINE || c == '\n' ) 
    {
        line[i] = '\0'; 
        printf( "%s\n", squeeze( line, s2 ) );
        i = 0;
    } 
    else 
    {
        line[i++] = c;
    }
}
```